# Writing Mocha tests with IcedCoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript, mocha.js, iced-coffeescript

I'm trying to run some database queries in a Mocha test but I'm running into some problems.

Here's the test (using Mongoose):

```
it.only "should create some objects", (done) ->
  await models.MyModel1.count defer(err, oldModel1Count)
  await models.MyModel2.count defer(err, oldModel2Count)

  # ... do some stuff

  await models.MyModel1.count defer(err, newModel1Count)
  await models.MyModel2.count defer(err, newModel2Count)

  assert.equal oldModel1Count + 1, newModel1Count
  assert.equal oldModel2Count + 1, newModel2Count
```

The command for running the tests:

```
mocha --compilers coffee:iced-coffee-script --require iced-coffee-script --require mocha --colors --recursive test"
```

The error happens on the first line:

```
ReferenceError: err is not defined
```

I can only assume that it is attempting to use normal CoffeeScript to execute this code, so it thinks that `defer` is a function and attempts to evaluate `err`.

Is it possible to write the Mocha tests in IcedCoffeeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me

```
mocha --require ./fix_my_iced_tests.js --compilers coffee:coffee-script
```

create fix_my_iced_tests.js

```
require('iced-coffee-script').register()
```

create test/some_test.coffee (this make sure that fix actually works)

```
assert = require 'assert'

describe 'test section', ()->
  it 'is ok', (done)->
    await setTimeout (defer next), 100
    assert.strictEqual(1, 1)
    done()
    return
  return
```

You should recieve something like this

```
  Type subdsl
    √ is ok (102ms)


  1 passing (109ms)
```

without fix you should recieve something like this

```
ReferenceError: next is not defined
```

**--- EDITED ---**

Much better option found [here](https://github.com/maxtaco/coffee-script/issues/138)

```
mocha --compilers coffee:iced-coffee-script/register
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's still relevant, but it's 2015 now, and Node.js has first-class support for Promises and Generators, which enables you to write your code [exactly as concise and elegant](https://www.pandastrike.com/posts/20141114-faking-co-routines) as IcedCoffeeScript, but with a lot less wrinkles.